# how do I find a 10-digit number according to the first three numbers in the text? Python

Tags: python, string, numbers, find

I need to find all 10 digit numbers in the text starting with a certain number series. There is a example:

**a_string = "Some text 6401104219 and 6401104202 and 2201104202"**

**matches = ["240", "880", "898", "910", "920", "960", "209", "309", "409", "471", "640"]**

**result is: 6401104219, 6401104202**

Comment: Did you try anything? What is exactly you are stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and `str.startswith`:

```
import re

result = [s for s in re.findall(r"\d{10}", a_string) if any(map(s.startswith, matches))]
# ['6401104219', '6401104202']
```

If you know the prefixes are all 3 digits long, you can do better:

```
matches = set(matches)

result = [s for s in re.findall(r"\d{10}", a_string) if s[:3] in matches]
```

You will have to change the regex to `r"\b(\d{10})\b"` if you want to exclude possible 10-digit prefixes of longer numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use re.

```
import re
a_string = "Some text 6401104219 and 6401104202 and 2201104202 and    640110420212"
matches = ["240", "880", "898", "910", "920", "960", "209", "309", "409", "471", "640"]
result = re.findall(r"\b(?:" + r"|".join(matches)+r")\d{7}\b", a_string)

print(result)
# ['6401104219', '6401104202']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can regex.

- Find all the 10-digit numbers
- Filter out the numbers which starts from the given elements in matches list

The code :

```
import re

a_string = "Some text 6401104219 and 6401104202 and 2201104202"

matches = ["240", "880", "898", "910", "920",
           "960", "209", "309", "409", "471", "640"]

match = re.findall(r'\d{10}', a_string)  # finding all the 10 digit numbers

# filtering out the numbers which starts from the given elements in matches


ans = [i for i in match if any(map(i.startswith, matches))]
# OR 
# ans = [i for i in match if i[:3] in matches] # if lenght is 3 only then simply check its existence in list
print(ans)
# ['6401104219', '6401104202']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_string = "Some text 6401104219 and 6401104202 and 2201104202 and    640110420212"
matches = ["240", "880", "898", "910", "920", "960", "209", "309", "409", "471", "640"]

a_string_list=a_string.split(' ')
for i in a_string_list:
    for j in matches:
        if i.startswith(j) and len(i)==10:
            print(i)
            break
```